# iPhone 6.1 Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I am just starting to learn programming for the iPhone and I had a very general question.

I was wondering why is it that when I run my program in xcode, even though I am programming for iPhone 5, when I run the "iPhone 6.1 Simulator" instead of a iPhone 5 Simulator and iPhone 4 pops up?

I am on Mac OS X - 10.7.5
And Xcode version 4.6

Could it be because the apple id I used to download xcode with only has an iPhone 4 and not a 5?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood you right. Please are not confused by the appearnce of the iphone frame around the iPhone simulator. The versin number does not at all refer to the product name of the hardware. It refes to the iOS version that is used by the simulator at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your simulator device to other screen resolutions go to `Simulator - Device - Retina 4 inch` (for iPhone 5) and `Retina 3.5 inch` for iPhone 4/4S. Use `iPhone` for iPhone 3GS resolution.

In the `Window` menu you can change the scale to fit your Mac's screen resolution. (I use 75% for iPhone Retina 3.5 inch).

I also suggest you download `iOS 5.1 Simulator` if you want to deploy apps for `iOS 5.1` and up - it comes really handy and it actually does have some differences from `iOS 6`.

Comment: Will developing with the iPhone 6.1 Simulator not allow the apps to run on anything 6.1 or below?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome! It's not the development you do on the simulator, it's testing. To allow support of iOS5 devices for your app you have to change `Minimal Deployment Target` setting of your XCode project to be iOS 5 or whatever you want it to be. Apps for iOS 5, for example, may run well on an iOS 5 device but may behave differently on an iOS 6 device. That's what simulators and their names (iPhone 6.1) are for.

Comment: @SergiusGee How about running an universal application in iPad with iPhone 3.5 and 4 inch resolutions(I am aware of how to run in iPhone normal resolution,i.e., by setting Target device to iPhone though)

Answer (score 1):

Choosing "iPhone 6.1 Simulator" is telling Xcode that you want to use the currently selected iPhone simulator with iOS 6.1.

To select the specific iPhone simulator you need to click on the Hardware then Device menu in the simulator.

Your Apple Id and your registered devices have nothing to do with this.