# Xcode simulator Add iphone5

Tags: xcode, cordova, simulator

I want to test my phonegap-jqm application in iphone 5 simulator.
Currently the application perfectly working in ipad 6.0 simulator.

How to add/install simulator (iphone5) in xcode 4.5.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

**iPhone 5 (4-inch retina)**

If you want to test in iPhone 5, select appropriate configuration in iOS Simulator Hardware -> Device
[image]

**Download iOS 5 simulator**

If you want to install another version of iOS simulator, go to Xcode preferences -> Downloads and download simulator you want.
[image]

Ensure that your project target is 5.x or lower to run on iOS 5.x

BR.
Eugene

Answer (score 1):

It should be installed by default. 
You should check wether you have your app built for iPhone and iPad (Universal) or only for the iPad. In the picture down, the app will run both on iPhone and iPad, but on iPad it will be in an iPhone simulation mode with a `2x` button down.

[image]

If it is built only for the iPad you won't be able to test it on the iPhone. Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254918/iphone-6-1-simulator/15254945#15254945).