# Which iPhone is being simulated on my screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

I'm new to iOS development, and I don't use iPhones much. I'm very used to how Android handles emulators and such, but since there are only really two iPhone physical sizes (I know I have to take retina into account, but that's pixels and not size), how do I know which one is showing up on the simulator? If I'm using the iPhone 4S in the simulator, is there a way to use the iPhone 5? Lastly, can I run two simulators at once (you can run many emulators at once with Android). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change/check the simulation's device at

> Hardware->Device->iPhone

[Screenshot Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270925/1031955) (first pic.)

**UPDATE :** You can run multiple simulators at once. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3717027/1031955). I haven't try it myself yet though.

Comment: Aha, I didn't realize the menu's changed when the simulator is selected. Thanks for answering the simulator question as well.

Comment: You're welcome. I also found a possible method that allow you to run multiple simulators at once as well. see update.